# Query Parameter is not getting matched when using WireMock

Tags: wiremock, http-request-parameters, wiremock-standalone

I am trying to hit the WireMock with following stub but it seems that the query param is not getting matched. Here is the response:

```
                                               Request was not matched
                                               =======================

-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Closest stub                                             | Request                                                  |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                                                           |
GET                                                        | GET
/mpp-pricing/v1/agreements\?accountId=.*                   | /mpp-pricing/v1/agreements?accountId=5388afaf-ee3d-44ed-a<<<<< URL does not match. When using a regex, "?" should be "\\?"
                                                           | b2a-0035156bb0a2
                                                           |
```

and this is the stub I used:

```
{
  "request": {
    "method": "GET",
    "urlPathPattern": "/mpp-pricing/v1/agreements\\?accountId=.*"
  },
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I have faced the same issue myself but I was able to overcome by re-writing the matcher using queryParameters.

Maybe you could do something similar and re-write your pattern as below:

```
{
    "request": {
        "method": "GET",
        "urlPathPattern": "/mpp-pricing/v1/agreements",
        "queryParameters": {
           "accountId": {
              "matches": ".*"
           }
        }
    }
},
```

Answer (score 0):

You can re-write the url and query parameters by using filters, an example class UrlAndHeadersModifyingFilter in documentation https://wiremock.org/docs/extending-wiremock

```
public static class UrlAndHeadersModifyingFilter extends StubRequestFilter {

    @Override
    public RequestFilterAction filter(Request request) {
        Request wrappedRequest = RequestWrapper.create()
                .transformAbsoluteUrl(url -> url + "?extraQueryParam=123")
                .addHeader("X-Custom-Header", "headerval")
                .wrap(request);

        return RequestFilterAction.continueWith(wrappedRequest);
    }

    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return "url-and-header-modifier";
    }
} 

new WireMockServer(wireMockConfig()
  .extensions(UrlAndHeadersModifyingFilter.class));
```

Answer (score 0):

It is essential to understand the differences between: `urlPattern`and `urlPathPattern`. I hope this post helps.

If you choose `urlPathPattern` you can't use a URL with query params.

In this way, the stub that should work is:

```
  "request": {
    "method": "GET",
    "urlPattern": "/mpp-pricing/v1/agreements\\?accountId=.*"
  },
```

It's useless the `urlPathPattern` here because the regex would only match on the path. In this case, the regex is in the query param so you need to add a `queryParameters` object with a `matches` expression as @Dio answered earlier.

So this is the result using `urlPath` and `queryParameters`:

```
{
    "request": {
        "method": "GET",
        "urlPath": "/mpp-pricing/v1/agreements",
        "queryParameters": {
           "accountId": {
              "matches": ".*"
           }
        }
    }
},
```